# How to count occurrence of elements in a single column of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['a', 'a', 'b', 'd']})
In [7]: data
Out[7]:
  name
0    a
1    a
2    b
3    d
```

What I want to do is to summarize

```
a 2
b 1
d 1
```

How can I do it?
Tried this but not good:

```
g = data.groupby('name')
g.count()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

hope this helps use [value_counts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['a', 'a', 'b', 'd']})

In [14]: data['name'].value_counts()
Out[14]: 
a    2
b    1
d    1
dtype: int64
```

or
As you have tried using [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
g=data.groupby('name')['name']

g.count()
Out[25]: 
name
a    2
b    1
d    1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```